# $u(x,t) = \frac{1}{\pi^{N/2}}\int u_0(x-2\sqrt{t}y)e^{-|y|^2}\ dy$, then $|u(x,t)|\le M(1+4\delta t)^{-N/2}e^{-\delta|x|^2/(1+4\delta t)}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

> Let $$u(x,t) = \frac{1}{\pi^{N/2}}\int_{\mathbb{R}^N}
>  u_0(x-2\sqrt{t}y)e^{-|y|^2}\ dy$$
>
> Show that if there are constants $M, \delta>0$ such that $$|u_0(x)|\le
>  Me^{-\delta|x|^2}, x\in\mathbb{R}^N$$ then $$|u(x,t)|\le M(1+4\delta
>  t)^{-N/2}e^{-\delta|x|^2/(1+4\delta t)}$$ Conclude that if $u_0$ has
>   compact support, then $\lim_{t\to \infty} u(x,t) = 0$ uniformly

$$|u(x,t)| = \frac{1}{\pi^{N/2}}\left|\int_{\mathbb{R}^N}
 u_0(x-2\sqrt{t}y)e^{-|y|^2}\ dy\right|\le \frac{1}{\pi^{N/2}}\int_{\mathbb{R}^N}
 \left|u_0(x-2\sqrt{t}y)e^{-|y|^2}\right|\ dy $$

So I need to find a bound for $\left|u_0(x-2\sqrt{t}y)e^{-|y|^2}\right|$ using  $|u_0(x)|\le
 Me^{-\delta|x|^2}$

Ok,

$$\left|u_0(x-2\sqrt{t}y)e^{-|y|^2}\right|\le Me^{-\delta|x|^2}e^{-|y|^2} = Me^{-\delta|x|^2-|y|^2}$$

I tried working with $-\delta|x|^2-|y|^2$ and using $|a|^2 -|b|^2 \le |a-b|^2$ or something like that but it looks like it won't work.

**UPDATE:**

the right bound is $|u_{0}(x-2\sqrt{t}y)| \leq M e^{-\delta |x-2\sqrt{t}y|^2}$ so we get

$$|u(x,t)|\le \frac{1}{\pi^{N/2}}\int_{\mathbb{R}^N}|u_{0}(x-2\sqrt{t}y)e^{-|y|^2}|dy  \leq \frac{1}{\pi^{N/2}}\int_{\mathbb{R}^N}M e^{-\delta |x-2\sqrt{t}y|^2} e^{-|y|^2}dy =\\ \frac{1}{\pi^{N/2}}\int_{\mathbb{R}^N}M e^{-\delta |x-2\sqrt{t}y|^2 -|y|^2}dy  $$

Comment: Why do you think $$|u_{0}(x-2\sqrt{t}y) \leq M e^{-\delta |x|^2}$$ and not
 $$|u_{0}(x-2\sqrt{t}y| \leq M e^{-\delta |x-2\sqrt{t}y|^2}$$ ?

Comment: @DaveNine you're right

Comment: What you have now looks okay, I think you’re there if you just integrate that thing now.